# TYPO3: Using Regex in Typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Hey Guys is it possible to use an Regex with typoscript??

I exactly need it at the baseURL.

f.e. baseURL = http://example.com/ remove last slash (http://example.com)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with stdWrap.substring if config.baseURL has stdWrap. But it has not. And you should not remove the last slash at config.baseURL.

If you have stdWrap, you can use substring

```
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = http://example.com/
  10.stdWrap.substring = 0,-1
```

**Replacement via regular expression is implementent since TYPO3 4.6 [see TSref](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/5/#id2622216)**